# Как получить доступ к объекту через его handle?

Tags: delphi

Допустим, есть 2 объекта

```
    BMP,buf: tbitmap;
```

Нужно `buf:=bmp`, но только через handle или есть другой способ?

Например:

```
BMP,buf: tbitmap;  p:pointer;
p:=@bmp;
buf:=^p;
```

Но т.к. `tbitmap` - это и есть указатель на класс, то не получается )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение найдено:

```
var b1:tbitmap;   b2:hdc;
b2:=image1.Picture.Bitmap.Handle;
b1.Handle:=b2;
```

Теперь можно рисовать на `b1`, и при этом будет изменятся `b2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
bmp.assign(buf);
```

или наоборот

```
buf.Assign(bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
buf.canvas.handle:=bmp.canvas.handle;
```

Этот вариант полностью перезапишет содержимое `buf` на `bmp`.

Comment: нет. Я хочу работать с BMP через указатель или что-нибудь подобное

Answer (score 0):

```
TBitmap(^buf). //не помню точно который из символов ставить и ставить ли...
TBitmap(@buf). //так что попытайте удачу со всеми тремя вариантами
TBitmap(buf).  //<<
```